# C# - Does casting preserve the reference to the original object?

Tags: c#

If I cast an object in C#, does it still reference the original object cast?

As an example, if I create a method to change an object and then cast that object depending on specific implementation called, does the original object get preserved?

```
    public bool CallChangeString()
    {
        String str = "hello";
        ChangeObject(str);
        return String.Equals("HELLO", str);
    }

    public void ChangeObject(Object obj)
    {
        String str = obj as String;
        str.ToUpper(); // pretend for the sake of this that this changes str to upper case
    }
```

In this case, would the String.Equals return true or false?

Are there any situations where casting would cause the new object to not preserve it's reference?

Comment: What is it returning when you test it? Is there any issue you are facing with the above code?

Comment: @HenkHolterman `Equals` returns a boolean.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, so what do you think I meant when I said, "would the String.Equals return true or false"?

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: Isn't the point of StackOverflow so people in the future don't have to test stuff?

Comment: @Shub-Nullgurath No, its purpose is to teach people how to avoid problems or how to handle them, not to check if there *is* any.

Comment: You don't even change `str` anywhere - so they'd obviously be the same. If you want to see how casts affect things, you need to allow them to affect things!

Comment: @HimBromBeere , I broke down a specific and complex problem I was having to do with casting and reference preservation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depends on what cast you are doing. You can think of two main groups of casting:

1. Those that preserve identity
2. Those that don't

Well, thats not very helpful, that is precisely what you are asking.

What casts *don't* preserve identity? All those that entail a representational change in the object itself, that is, the *bits* that make up the object *change*.

Examples? All casts between value types: `int` to `long`, `int` to `double`, etc., any boxing or unboxing conversion, etc. The bits that make up a `long` are very different from those that make up an `int`.

More examples? Any user defined cast operator, explicit or implicit. Why? Because user defined casts that preserve identity are disallowed by the compiler simply because the compiler already does them for you:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
     public static implicit operator object(Foo foo) => return foo; //Compile time error     
     public static implicit operator IFoo(Foo foo) => return foo; //compile time error.

     public static explicit operator Bar(Foo foo) => return new Bar(foo);
}
```

Note the general pattern of user defined casts:

- any valid operator will always have a `new` lurking
  around in whatever it returns. Thats telling you right away that the
  cast can not preserve identity... you are returning a new object.
- There is no way you can implement a user defined identity preserving conversion. Thats not a problem because there is no *need*, those conversions are already provided by C#'s type system.

So, what *are* identity preserving casts or conversions? Well, those that *don't* touch the object all; *reference conversions*.

Huh? But wait, The whole point is that I'm *casting* the object, how can that be?

In reference conversions you are *only "casting" the reference* pointing to the object. The object is always the same. This, of course, only makes sense in reference types and that is why value types don't have identity preserving conversions; there are no references to value types unless they are boxed.

Examples? `object` to `string`, `Foo` to `IFoo`, `Giraffe` to `Animal`, etc.

Do note that reference types can very well implement user defined casts too, but these will not preserve identity.

All that said, this is the rule of the thumb:

- Any cast provided/allowed by the language type system itself preserves identity. These are, exclusively, reference conversions and only apply to reference types.
- Any user defined cast, explicit or implicit, *does not* preserve identity (rememeber, `(long)2` is a user defined cast, somebody had to implement it in the class `System.Int64`).

So, answering your question, `var str = obj as string` is a reference conversion, which means that `ReferenceEquals(str, obj)` is `true`; `str` and `obj` point to exactly the same object, the only difference is the type of the reference.

Comment: Well, the "preserve identity" comes down to "what does the (user-defined) cast return"? Usually it is a new instance of the given type, thus it *surely* can´t preserve the identity.

Comment: @HimBromBeere True, the question is: can you think of a valid user defined cast that doesn't return a new object? (I don't mean that the `new` needs to be exlicit)

Answer (score 3):

1. strings are immutable, so you can't change them. However you can create new instances:

   ```
   myString = myString.Replace("", ".");
   ```

   Be aware that `myString` is a completely new instance which is not related to the original string. Thus even if you assign something different to `myString` this won't affect your calling code that relies on the original instance.

   In your example `str.ToUpper()` won't change anything, as `ToUpper` returns a new string instead of changing the current (`str`) instance.
2. casting creates a new *reference* to the same instance. Thus modifications to an instance are reflected in all of its references, be it casted instances or just re-references

   ```
   var a = (MyType) myInstance;
   a.MyProperty = 4;
   ```

   After the last statement both `a` and `myInstance` have the property `MyProperty` set to `4`, because both variables `a` and `myInstance` reference the same instance of `MyType`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that str.ToUpper() doesn't change the string itself. Thanks for that! I've updated it with a few minor changes.

Answer (score -2):

Change your method like this and see result )

```
public bool CallChangeString()
    {
        String str = "hello";
        ChangeObject(str);
        return String.Equals("HELLO", str);
    }
```