# What is object casting?

Tags: c#, object, casting

I'm a bit confused about what exactly object casting is and what it's used for.
I've read the MSDN documentation about [Casting and type conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx), where I can see that for explicit conversion you need to use a cast operator. I understand the example given in the documentation, that you need to use a cast operator if you might lose some data when converting one type to another.

I'm just confused about how you cast objects? I'm assuming objects are instances of a class that might hold more information than just a simple data type? So how, why and when would you need to cast an object?

I've seen an example of casting an object, which is simply:

```
SomeType name = (SomeType)obj;
```

Am I missing something, or is this object casting? If it is, in what scenarios would you need to cast an object like this?

Comment: unboxing is one case.. We had to do too much casting before the introduction of generic methods in c#. This is because too many methods used the `object` parameter like the non-generic version `List`. Think about events where sender if of type `object` and you need to cast it to `Button` for example. Sure the `as` operator is preferred, but i'm just trying to explain a valid case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use the cast operator when there is no *implicit* cast available that the compiler can verify is safe. If there is one and the compiler is sure the cast will succeed then it will do it for you automatically.

Now, why should I use a cast? You should use a cast when you either:

- Have an object of type `A` and you need an object of type `B` and
  there is a way to convert an `A` into a `B`.
- You have a reference of type `A` to an object and you need a
  reference of type `B` to that same object and both `A` and `B` are valid reference types to that object.

Another way to think about it is:

- When you know better than the compiler and you know an object is a
  type the compiler can't.
- When an object is not of a certain type but you know there is a valid conversion to that type.

And this brings up a way to group casts based upon what the cast is really doing:

- Casts that preserve identity.
- Casts that don't.

The 1rst group are what we call *reference conversions*. These don't change the object at all, they simply change the type of the reference pointing to the object (evidently, they only apply to reference types, value types can not have reference conversions because you can't get a reference to a value type). Note that this type of cast is provided by the language itself, you *can't* implement reference conversions.

The second group are all the conversions that entail a representational change in the object, that is, the bits of the object returned by the cast are different to the the bits of the casted object. These type of casts are the `implicit` and `explicit` operators you can implement in any C# class/struct.

You can read more about this [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41762204/767890).

Ok all that is very interesting, but can you give me concrete examples? Yes, of course:

1. The compiler knows enough:

   ```
   interface IFoo { }
   class Foo: IFoo { }
   IFoo foo = new Foo();
   ```

   There is an implicit cast from `Foo` to `IFoo` in the last statement: `IFoo foo = (IFoo)(new Foo());`. This cast will succeed *always* and the compiler *knows* there is an implicit cast (a reference conversion) from `Foo` to `IFoo` available, so it will do it for you.
2. I know better than the compiler:

   ```
   object o = "Hello"; //'compiler knows enough' as all types are derived from object
   var s = (string)o;
   ```

   Here I *know* `o` is really a string and I'm telling the compiler: even though you think `o` is an object, trust me, I know its a string.

   This is also a reference conversion. The string `Hello` isn't touched in any way, the only thing we are changing is the reference pointing to it.
3. I know a given object of type A is convertible to another object of type B although no reference conversion exists.

   ```
   short s = 1;
   int i = s;
   ```

   Note that a `short` *is not* an `int` but there happens to be a method (a cast operator) that *knows* how to convert a `short` to an `int`. Here we have an implicit cast from `short` to `int`. `s` and `i` have very different bits, but somebody implemented the necessary logic that turns a short into an int.

   Now note that this is an implicit cast, you don't need to explicitly cast the short although nothing stops you from doing it. Its perfectly valid to do: `int i = (int)s;`.

   ```
   double d = 1.5;
   int i = (int)d;
   ```

   Here we have the same type of cast, but now its explicit. If you would have written `int i = d` you'd get a compile time error because the cast is not implicit.

   This brings up an interesting point that you seem to be conflating with casts; information loss. Its a good practice that implicit casts *do not loose information* while explicit cast are allowed to do so. This seems reasonable, you don't want the compiler to implicitly cast things losing information without telling you; when you cast a `short` into an `int` there is no risk, any `short` fits into an `int`. That is obviously not true when casting from `double` to `int`, hence the cast is implemented as explicit. (Note on *implemented*, this isn't enforced by the language, its a design decision of whoever wrote the class defining the cast operators).

Answer (score 1):

A simple valid example goes back to older versions of C#. `List<T>` didn't exist in that version and in order to store a collection of data you had to use a non-generic collection:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
   list.Add(1);
   list.Add(2);
   list.Add(3);

   int total = 0;
   foreach(object item in list)
      total += (int)item; // without casting, compiler never knows item is int

   Console.WriteLine("Total = {0}", total);
}
```

Another valid example is events, most events use the signature `(object sender, EventArgs e)`. In order to access the elements of the sender, a button for example, then you need to cast:

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
Console.WriteLine(btn.Text);
```

It is a better practice to use the `as` operator over the normal casting to prevent null reference exception, but the above is just to provide valid examples.

Answer (score 0):

You would cast to a specific object, whenever you want to use that specific type of object.
Another way to cast to another type is

```
SomeType x = obj as SomeType;
```

Here you won't get an exception when obj is null. You should do a check for == null though.