# The difference between type casting and a polymorphic function call?

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism

I'm reading Rihter's book on c# and I am wondering how type casting works.

Say I have this code:

```
    class Parent
    {
        public virtual void DoStuff()
        {
            //... some code
        }
    }

    class Child : Parent
    {
        public override void DoStuff()
        {
            // .. some different code
        }
    }
```

Now in the Main() function I call this:

```
        Parent child = new Child();
        child.DoStuff();
```

How is this different from type casting? According to Rihter the CLR will follow the child's link to the child's type-object (Child) in memory and retrieve the pointer to the Child.DoStuff() version of the method. To me that sounds like the same operation as this:

```
        ((Child)child).DoStuff();
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `To me that sounds like the same operation as this:` Well, it is (if you squint hard enough) - but its simpler to write (and completely safe - you **know** the "cast" will work in `child.DoStuff()`). Why would you want to explicitly do the cast? _Note it wouldn't be equivalent if `new` was used rather than `override`._ Also keep in mind that the code calling `DoStuff` might be completely separate to the code doing the instantiation - such that the former doesn't know whether the `(Child)` cast is safe or not (i.e. it is clear in your code example, but only because the two lines are adjacent).

Comment: Try adding a third class that inherits `Parent` (i.e. `Child2`), and try to cast to `Child2` when the variable is already instantiated by `Child`

Comment: It's not the same as casting. The act of `public override void DoStuff()` replaces the `DoStuff` call site so that all instances of `Child` will call that `DoStuff` regardless of the type of the variable that hold a reference to them. There is no casting. There is just one `DoStuff` for an object of type `Child`. Casting does not change the type of the instance.

Comment: Ok but how about performance? Does child.DoStuff() cost the same as ((Child)child).DoStuff()? As opposed to Parent p = new Parent(); p.DoStuff();? Or even better - calling a method from a structure (that cannot be overridden)?

Comment: `Ok but how about performance?` https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ In the real world, very few systems are going to have this kind of issue as their performance bottleneck (vs say database access).

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41762204/767890) might be useful.

Comment: @InBetween although a very interesting read, that's not what I am looking for. I am wondering where the CLR gets the address of the ToString() method for float/int/byte which are all different, when the stack representation of float/int/byte has no reference to the Type object. Does the heap hold an exemplar of the float/int/byte objects? If so, how does the value in the stack know its' type?

Comment: `when the stack representation of float/int/byte has no reference to the Type object` It **does** have a reference to the `Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this different from type casting?

Polymorphism is very different than type casting and a key foundation of OO programming languages. Your example doesn't really showcase anything about the usefulness of the feature.

Consider the following example:

```
 abstract class Animal {
     public abstract string MakeSound(); }

 void PrintSound(Animal animal) { Console.WriteLine(animal?.MakeSound(); }
```

And now the typical scenario of a callsite with an argument only known at runtime:

```
var animal = makeUserChooseAnimal(); //no idea what animal this will be
PrintSound(animal);
```

Where exactly would you fit in the cast you are asking about? But polymorphism and the virtual call will make it possible, that no matter what animal is really passed into `PrintSound`, the appropiate `MakeSound()` will be called.

Now, if what you are interested in is understanding how the CLR figures out what method to call, then I'd recommend you read Eric Lippert's three part series on the subject, starting [here](https://ericlippert.com/2011/03/17/implementing-the-virtual-method-pattern-in-c-part-one/).