# How can I return an array of different elements that inherit from the same class?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class A from which B and C inherit.
I have two lists: `listB` and `listC`, of the respective types.

I want to make a method that returns the two lists inside an array, like so:

```
public override List<A>[] GetAllItems()
{
    return new List<A>[2]
    {
        listB,
        listC
    };
}
```

However, when I try this approach, I get the following error, because I try to convert the inherited types incorrectly.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Lae.B>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Lae.A>' [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0029)

Is there some way to create this array **without converting** the elements?

---

**Note**: I am not using a struct or class, because I want the array to be of various sizes based on logic above.

Comment: I would suggest to use interfaces for that is the list objects are somewhat similar like id's,... if not you can use wrapper classes for the child lists

Comment: You can `listB.Cast<A>().ToList()`, unless that is what you mean by "converting the elements" - I don't class a cast as a conversion in this sense because your `B`s in your `listB` remain `B`s (look like A but can be cast back to B) rather than becoming As (A cannot be cast to B) but your opinion may differ

Comment: Perhaps keeping them separated would more easily achieve goals at the caller end; return a tuple of `(List<B>,List<C>)`  instead..

Comment: Could `GettAllItems` return a `IReadOnlyList<A>[]`? Or does each list need to remain mutable when accessed via the array?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I don’t what that is, but I would prefer if I had a reference.

Comment: @Lae You will have a reference to each list, `IReadOnlyList` just doesn't expose the mutational methods e.g. `Add`, but you can still access items via the index. [An example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZypP8I).

Comment: @Lae *won't I lose information and functionality?* - no. `object o = new StringBuilder(); (o as StringBuilder).Append("Hello world");` - it is still a StringBuilder inside `o`, it still has its text "Hello world", and it can be treated as a stringbuilder at any time by casting `o` to a StringBuilder. It is of course, a massive pain in the ass to cast all the time and makes for ugly code; you'd probably want to cast back.. But if you were going to do that you might as well just use the tuple I suggested and skip that "cast it all as A just to get it out of the method then uncast as B/C again"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<A>[] GetAllItems()
{
    var result = new List<A>[2] {
        listB.Cast<A>().ToList(),
        listC.Cast<A>().ToList(),
    };
    
    return result;
}
```

If you need to return array of `List`s - easiest way is to use `Cast` linq extension method.

In reference to the comments you have to remember that if you modify `listB` or `listC`, the change won't be reflected in the casted collections.

Anyway, if you need to have an access to the original `listB` / `listC` collections references, you can use `IEnumerable` instead of `List` in order to not be forced to "materialize" the results. Example:

```
public IEnumerable<A>[] GetAllItems()
{
    return new IEnumerable<A>[] {
        listB,
        listC,
    };
}
```

Now when you access eg. `allItems[0]` it will reference to the original `listB` collection.

Comment: Well, you don't *have to* - there are other ways to skin that cat

Comment: @CaiusJard Since I am casting from B back to A, won't I lose information and functionality?

Comment: @CaiusJard of course i agree with you. Anyway, i think this is the way that is "closest" to the code from the question.

Comment: Also not that this creates 2 new lists, and updating the original `listB` / `listC` will have no impact on the object returned from `GetAllItems`.

Comment: Regarding casting, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41762204/2482123) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because instance of B is an also A but instance of List of B is not also List of A.

You should box the types in the collection, you can use Cast function of in the Linq namespace.

```
using System.Linq;

 List<A>[] GetAllItems()
   {
    var result = new List<A>[2] {
        listB.Cast<A>().ToList(),
        listC.Cast<A>().ToList(),
    };
    return result;
   }
```

Or you can do that manualy.

```
List<A>[] GetAllItems()
{
    var boxedListB = new List<A>();
    var boxedListC = new List<A>();
    foreach (var item in listB)
    {
        boxedListB.Add(item);
    }
    foreach (var item in listC)
    {
        boxedListC.Add(item);
    }
    var result = new List<A>[2] {
         boxedListB,
         boxedListC
     };

    return result;
}
```

Or you can use Select function in System.Linq namespace.

```
List<A>[] GetAllItems()
{

    var result = new List<A>[2] {
         listB.Select(x=> x as A).ToList(),
         listC.Select(x=>x as A).ToList()
     };

    return result;
}
```

You can check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#:%7E:text=Boxing%20is%20the%20process%20of,value%20type%20from%20the%20object.) for more information about boxing/unboxing.